# Trying to tighten loose kitchen faucet

Tags: faucet, delta

The faucet rocks around a little on the countertop. I got a basin wrench and I cannot turn the nut. From the picture, does it look like the nut is corroded on? Is that a typical occurrence? Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "does it look like the nut is corroded"? Something looks dodgy there but it's difficult to see in that pic. "Is that a typical occurrence? " Yes, quite common to see some corrosion under there due to water seeping down from the deck and/or through the hose hole. Typically, those faucets come with a special tool for tightening them down (I always try to zip tie the tool to the faucet, underneath there somehow). Can you tell us the make and model of the faucet?

Comment: Have you tried *loosening* the nut too?

Comment: Yes I tried loosening. It would not budge.

Comment: I have the special tool. It is a plastic cylinder. I would need to undo the supply lines to be able to slip the tool on. I think with the basin wrench I was able to put way more force on that nut than I could with the special tool. The make is Delta. I could not find the model.

Comment: See also [How can I remove a rusted faucet nut?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/103422/remove-fastener-nut-for-kitchen-faucet-rusted?rq=1) and [What kind of tool can I use to tighten a faucet bolt in a tight place?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/127108/what-kind-of-tool-can-i-use-to-tighten-a-faucet-bolt-in-a-tight-place?rq=1)

Comment: Based on  your comments here and to my answer, it seems as though you just need to get that nut moving.  If you can't, you need to take a gamble on either destroying the faucet and replacing it, which has a fixed known cost, or paying a plumber to have a go.  A plumber with more experience may be able to do what you can't.  But they may fail, they may destroy the faucet anyway, and even if they get the nut off you may need a new faucet.  I think it's a bad  bet.  You could buy a bigger badder basin wrench.  You could try heat and penetrating oil to loosen the nut.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some random shots in the dark.

- That you cannot turn the nut, even to loosen it, does not help.   Look through this site and do everything you can to free the nut.  If you can't do that, you may be able to carefully saw off the nut and rescue the faucet with a replacement nut, or to destroy the faucet and replace it.  There's really no hope of reducing play if you can't move the nut.
- Some Delta faucets like yours require an optional spacer between the nut and the U-shaped metal gasket.  If the counter is too thin the nut bottoms out.  *Maybe* (and I emphasize this is a shot in the dark) your installation requires a spacer but it was not installed.
- Some Delta faucets are secured by two screws from the top and then the faucet body is secured from on top.  I don't think yours is one of these (you would see the ends of the screws underneath) but you would need the model and manual to be sure.
- Maybe the metal gasket having one of its fingers over the undermounted sink flange is a problem?   Probably not the problem but I would try anyway to turn it so it's entirely in contact with the counter.  But first you  need to be able to move the nut!

Comment: https://media.deltafaucet.com/MandI/85214%20Rev%20G.pdf Not sure if this is the right model but that Mounting Bracket looks the same. If your 4th bullet meant to turn that. I tried that. Maybe that gasket on the top side of the countertop got shoved up in the faucet, body, and the lack of that is causing the slop.

Comment: If that's the right manual my 2nd and 3rd suggestions are not useful.   What I do see is a special wrench for that nut.  Delta might send you one for free or cheaply.  Their customer service is very good.  Call them.

Comment: I have the plastic delta wrench.